# ServiceName is getting ignored while connecting to HA enabled HDFS from Java using RPC

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

Here is my build config method

```
private Configuration buildConfiguration() {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        if (connectivityDetail.isSecureMode()) {
            conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");
            conf.set("hadoop.http.authentication.type", "kerberos");
            conf.set("dfs.namenode.kerberos.principal", connectivityDetail.getHdfsServicePrincipal());
        }

        if (isHAEnabled()) {
            String hdfsServiceName = connectivityDetail.getHdfsServiceName();

            conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://" + hdfsServiceName);
            conf.set("dfs.ha.namenodes." + hdfsServiceName, "nn0,nn1");
            conf.set("dfs.nameservices", hdfsServiceName);
            conf.set("dfs.client.failover.proxy.provider." + hdfsServiceName,
                    "org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider");
            conf.set("dfs.namenode.rpc-address." + hdfsServiceName + ".nn1",
                    connectivityDetail.getNameNodeUris().get(0));
            conf.set("dfs.namenode.rpc-address." + hdfsServiceName + ".nn0",
                    connectivityDetail.getNameNodeUris().get(1));
        }
        return conf;

    }
```

**hdfsService name is incorrectly set into the configuration object but I am able to get FileSystem and everything is working correctly**. I am not sure why it is not using service name?

This is how I am creating Path

```
public static Path getHdfsResourceLocation(String resourceLocation) throws Exception {
         String[] hdfsURIs = OrchestrationConfigUtil.getHdfsUri();
         Path hdfsResourceLoc = null;
         if (isHAEnabled()) {
             hdfsResourceLoc = new Path(resourceLocation);
         } else {
             hdfsResourceLoc = FileContext.getFileContext(new URI(hdfsURIs[0])).makeQualified(new Path(resourceLocation));
         }
         return hdfsResourceLoc;
     }
```

Everything is working fine with wrong service name and I am not sure why?

Comment: There is no "wrong" service name. It is just an **arbitrary label** used to point to the appropriate properties. As long as you use the same label consistently in the conf, then your `FileSystem` will be able to resolve the IP:port of the active NameNode, and basta. The rest is just low-level TCP communication.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I think this is the correct answer but I am not able to find any doc/reference. Can you also provide some reference to clarify? Thanks.

Comment: Just look at the Apache documentation for HDFS "default" config, where *EXAMPLENAMESERVICE* is just a placeholder for an arbitrary label https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml

Comment: Thank you so much for this question. It answered something I've been struggling with for hours.